# ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image , unable to process images

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library, training-data, file-management

My code isn't able to read faces in images from the folder. It is showing Value error. Here is my code:

```
# Definition for extracting faces:
def extract_faces(filename, required_size=(224, 224)):
    pixels = pyplot.imread(filename)
    detector = MTCNN()
    results = detector.detect_faces(pixels)
    x1, y1, width, height = results[0]['box']
    x2, y2 = x1 + width, y1 + height
    face = pixels[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    image = Image.fromarray(face)
    image = image.resize(required_size)
    face_array = asarray(image)
    return face_array

# Definition for the face embedding:
def get_embeddings(filenames):
    faces = [extract_faces(f) for f in filenames]
    samples = asarray(faces, 'float32')
    samples = preprocess_input(samples, version=2)
    model = VGGFace(model = 'resnet50', include_top = False, input_shape = (224, 224, 3), pooling = 'avg')
    yhat = model.predict(samples)
    return yhat

# For getting the face embeddings:
embeddings = get_embeddings(faces)
```

The error is:

```
 File "c:/Users/Adarsh Narayanan/Realtime_FR_With_VGGFace2/retrainfaces.py", line 69, in <module>
    embeddings = get_embeddings(faces)  
  File "c:/Users/Adarsh Narayanan/Realtime_FR_With_VGGFace2/retrainfaces.py", line 29, in get_embeddings
    faces = [extract_faces(f) for f in filenames]  
  File "c:/Users/Adarsh Narayanan/Realtime_FR_With_VGGFace2/retrainfaces.py", line 29, in <listcomp>
    faces = [extract_faces(f) for f in filenames]  
  File "c:/Users/Adarsh Narayanan/Realtime_FR_With_VGGFace2/retrainfaces.py", line 22, in extract_faces
    image = Image.fromarray(face)  
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh Narayanan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2666, in fromarray
    return frombuffer(mode, size, obj, "raw", rawmode, 0, 1)  
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh Narayanan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2609, in frombuffer
    return frombytes(mode, size, data, decoder_name, args)  
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh Narayanan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2542, in frombytes
    im.frombytes(data, decoder_name, args)   
  File "C:\Users\Adarsh Narayanan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 825, in frombytes
    d.setimage(self.im)  

ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

Does anybody know what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

What if face detector results in `0` face(s) detected, you are not check for it.

You can check for number of faces detected should be `>=1`. Another point, `bilinear interpolation resize` for small detected face compared to `244x244`, would hamper the CNN results, you need another check here.

Comment: Its the predefined format for extracting faces and the face embedding of VGGFace2. That's why I used that format